# undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass for stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently upgraded rails application from `4` to `5.0.7.2`, I followed the necessary steps from the rails guide and did each upgrade as specified in the docs.

The rails server starts, but when I try to access the application in browser I see the following error message `undefined method` start_with?' for nil:NilClass`

this error seems to be happening when a call to `**stylesheet_link_tag**` is made

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass):
    10:     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/tbs/oc_logo.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    11:     <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    12:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'fontawesome-free-5.1.1-web/css/all.min', 'fontawesome-free-5.1.1-web/css/brands.min', 'fontawesome-free-5.1.1-web/css/fontawesome.min', 'fontawesome-free-5.1.1-web/css/regular.min', 'tbs/font' %>
    13:     <%= default_stylesheets %>
    14:     <%= default_javascripts %>
    15:     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

any help on how to fix this would be great, thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's an error in the asset pipeline. Probably some change in the asset pipeline from 4 to 5. Can you add your `application.css.scss` file to the question? Something that it is trying to load is coming up as nil.

Comment: @Beartech i don't have a `application.css.scss`. do i need to add it manually?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `stylesheet_link_tag` line? And where are the FontAwesome files stored? Have you precompiled assets?

Comment: @Beartech, if i remove the stylesheet_link_tag the login page load but the styles dont. font awesome files are stored in the same application. should i create a application.css.scss file and then load each css file from there?

Comment: I should have been more clear: exactly where are the font awesome files store? Please edit your question to include the directly listing for your assets folder and any sub folders so we can get an idea of your structure.